# How to get Row count by dynamically passing the table name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, row

```
create procedure qa_cc
@tablename varchar(500)

AS 

BEGIN
    -- Create two integer values
DECLARE @tableOneCount varchar(50), @tableTwoCount varchar(50)

-- Get the number of rows from the first table
SELECT @tableOneCount = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM'  + @tablename; 
    exec (@tableOneCount);           

select      @tableOneCount  ; 

END

exec qa_cc @tablename=table1
```

Comment: is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: The obvious question is how to get it working.  In the example query, `@tableOneCount` is out of scope during the `exec`.  A bit of friendliness towards new users can't hurt!

Answer (score 3):

You could use `sp_executesql`, like:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = N'select @cnt = count(*) from ' + @tablename;
declare @cnt int;
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@cnt int output', @cnt = @cnt output;
select @cnt;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT SUM(pa.rows) RowCnt
 FROM sys.tables ta
 INNER JOIN sys.partitions pa
 ON pa.OBJECT_ID = ta.OBJECT_ID
 WHERE ta.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND pa.index_id IN (1,0)
 and ta.name=@tablename
 GROUP BY ta.name
```

See http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/09/08/sql-server-find-row-count-in-table-find-largest-table-in-database-part-2/

Comment: @Andomar I *hate* dynamic SQL :)

Comment: Lots of things you can only do with dynamic SQL.  For example an efficient search through an orders table.  Without dynamic SQL you always end up with a query plan that's optimized for one particular kind of search.  (Dynamic SQL can be either server or client side.(

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you were missing a space after the FROM keyword which was reading `FROMTABLE` rather than `FROM Table`

```
DECLARE @TABLE NVARCHAR(100)
SET @TABLE = 'CLIENT' -- YOUR TABLE NAME

EXEC('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @TABLE)
```

Comment: `exec` requires a string literal or parameter as argument.  You can't concatenate in place.

Comment: @Andomar I tested the query before posting the answer it works fine SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Nice, that must be a 2008 imrpovement.  You learn something new every day here! +1

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TableRowCount]
@tableName text
AS
EXEC ('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @tableName)
RETURN @@ROWCOUNT
```

I hope that helps. Thank you.

Comment: @@ROWCOUNT is 1 in this case (being the one row that gets returned)